# Boost: How to get a subtree form an existing property tree?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-propertytree

I am trying to get a subtree from a `boost::ptree` using `get_child` like this:

I have:

```
class ConfigFile
{
  ptree pt;
  ConfigFile(const string& name)
  {
    read_json(name, pt);
  }
  ptree& getSubTree(const string& path)
  {
    ptree spt = pt.get_child(path);
    return spt;
  }
}
```

and when I call

```
ConfigFile cf("myfile.json");
ptree pt = cf.getSubTree("path.to.child")
```

the function crashes after return saying

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::length_error'
```

Can someone help me with this? what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're returning a reference to local. That won't work. Read this:

[Can a local variable's memory be accessed outside its scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope/6445794#6445794)

Fix:

```
ptree getSubTree(const string& path)
{
     return pt.get_child(path);
}
```

Your result was a manifestition of [Undefined Behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) and could be different on different days, compilers, runs...

Comment: Thanks, I have found another way [here](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=25033&seqNum=3) by creating a pointer on the stack, but your solution is better.

Comment: That "pointer on the stack" article is old, and predates C++11. Sehe's answer allows efficient move semantics, which are new to C++11.